# Entity Framework 6 just deleted my database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using MVC 5 with Entity Framework 6, automatic migrations are disabled, no seed is used and I'm scripting out my updates to production.

I'll hold up my hands and say I'm fairly new to MVC and EF.

I just uploaded a new codebase to production, and forgot that the model had changed. When I went to login to the new version, it threw and error page. Fine, I forgot to script the latest migration - I did that, hooked up to SSMS and found that the database was gone.

Slight panic, restore from backup (I'm not that daft!) and apply the migration and everything starts working as it should.

Why did my code delete the entire database when the model had changed? As said, automatic migrations are disabled and this behaviour doesn't happen on development machines, they throw an error about the model having been changed.

---

Edit to add: Whilst looking at the Initialisation patterns in Fernanda's answer, none of them say "Drop the database and then do nothing else". My database was dropped, the MDF and LDF gone, nothing is SSMS and nothing recreated in its place. If a blank database was created in its place I'd understand a bit more. That said, the user account had DBO on the database but not master, so would have been able to drop the database but not create a new one?

Comment: I don't know the answer but I always make sure I put `Database.SetInitializer<TContext>(null);` in the `OnModelCreating()` of my context class.

Comment: Seems prudent. I think my surprise is that it doesn't happen on any of the dev environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this about Database Initialization Strategies in Code-First:

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

Check your dbcontext initialization and be sure that the option DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges is comment

//Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges());

Comment: I have no initializer set, so I'd assume it's the default `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` - which is the exact behaviour I saw on my development environment.

Comment: You can also set db initializer in the configuration file. Check it for each environment. Are both equals?

Comment: You mean the Web.config?

Comment: Yes. In same place your enviroments production and development are different. Check the web.config or app.config

Comment: It's a web app and the `web.config`'s are identical.